# Filtering returned consul.io services on tag

Tags: consul

I was wondering if there is a way to filter the services consul returns me using tags.

The endpoint:

```
/v1/catalog/services
```

returns a map of services to lists of tags and requires me to parse the services after they are returned.

I was wondering if there is some way to pass the tag (or tags) I want as a query parameter to the endpoint and get a map back that is already filtered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its supported by the `?tags=...` query parameter to the individual service:
https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/http/catalog.html#catalog_service

Otherwise one could just parse the returned json from catalog/services.

Comment: Sorry I didn't approve this sooner. This functionality did not exists when I asked the question but is useful for people now.

Comment: This answer is misleading. The author originally asked about API to query services by tag, but not an individual service by name and tag (as you suggest).

Answer (score 2):

Based on the [docs](http://www.consul.io/docs/agent/http/catalog.html#catalog_services) and my own experiments this doesn't appear to be supported, agree that it would be useful.

Comment: Agree. This link also says this is not supported: https://github.com/hashicorp/consul/issues/4811